# What are the problems and their solutions when working off-line with TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, offline

Since the connection with the TFS server at my office is not stable, I often work with the codes in offline mode (here's [how to work offline quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934875/how-to-work-offline-with-tfs)).

The regular problem I get after the system goes online is the merging step which makes me stumble around the codes to get the codes online. I don't understand why the same problem doesn't happen when I work online from the beginning!

So, my question is what are the problems when working offline with TFS? And their solutions/notices to get back to online codes?

Comment: Dou you work disconnected (totally removing all SC bindings) or use the 'Temporarily work offline' option in such a case? In case of the first option it's no surprise that you have increased merging effort - you definitely shouldn't go this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insure that you will not have to merge, you can check out a file or files with the lock option.  This does not allow anyone to either check in or check-out on that particular file while you have it locked.

Understand that this could hamper productivity with fellow workers if they need to edit that same file.

Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181419.aspx).