# Visual studio thinks files are checked in when they aren't

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I just had Visual Studio fail on a commit due to a merge conflict and when I was done I had about 10 files that it thought were checked in that in reality never made it to TFS.

I ended up having to compare every file I might have changed and adding a single space to the ones I did... quite tedious.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to tell which files have been changed in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio will recheck all files when you change from offline mode to online.

If you don't mind losing the changes, you can also just re-checkout everything with the option to overwrite files enabled.

Comment: How do I switch to offline mode?

Comment: @cwolves: Good question, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934875/how-to-work-offline-with-tfs/934890#934890