# Disable auto opening of repositories

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Ever since I started using git, whenever I open my visual studio, this appears:

[image]
And then if I make a new project, it gets added to the repository. Is there any way to disable this and allow me to manually open repositories? I see no such option in Tools > Source control
This is very annoying.
I have Git tools 1.4.1, Git extensions 1.0.5 installed as extensions.

Comment: Which version of the GIT plugin are you using in the Visual Studio

Comment: Git tools 1.4.1, Git extensions 1.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Since [git tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) is integrated by default in Visual Studio 2013+, what you can check is:

- making sure [Git Extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8f594baa-e44e-4114-8381-e175ace0fe97) are *not* installed (they are for VS 2005 to 2013 anyway)
- check if the issue persits

The [OP Empereur Aiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3964654/empereur-aiman) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270376/disable-auto-opening-of-repositories/33318337#comment54467749_33318337):

> I ended up using **[Git Source Control Provider 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51e11ccc-6334-4873-912d-bf5025eb115d)** , not the microsoft one :) And it seemed to have solved the problem.

Comment: So uninstalled both git tools and git extensions. But it stills does the same thing :/

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Then it is a feature from VS 2015 (which has git built-in). I'll check on that front.

Comment: Did you get to know about anything?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman I have not, I suspect it is built-in in the way git is integrated with VS 2015

Comment: Yes. But before I first started a git project, these stuff never happened.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman and those projects that you are opening, are they in a git repo? (is there a `.git` folder in them or in the parent folders of those projects)

Comment: What happens is when I make a new project, it automatically goes to the repo at another place in my harddrive. Yes that folder has a .git file.

Comment: I went to Tools> Source Control. Then selected "None". Then it works normally, created new projects in the correct folder (not in a repo).
Whenever I select Source control to microsoft git provider, The message in the OP shows in output and new projects are created at the repo again.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Did you at one point follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/get-started and clone a git repo as described in this page?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman So if you were to go to the "Team Explorer"  view of Visual Studio 2015, there wouldn't be an active git repo?

Comment: There is always an active repo there : http://prntscr.com/8v9v15
Always when I open VS

Comment: @EmpereurAiman there should be a way to close it or to "unload" it. May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934875/how-to-work-offline-with-tfs#comment43643260_934890 ?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475.aspx is a good read too. Maybe clearing the cache? (search for "Q: How do I clear the cache on client computers?")

Comment: I ended up using [Git source control provider](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51e11ccc-6334-4873-912d-bf5025eb115d) not the microsoft one :) And it seemed to have solved the problem. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.