# Visual Studio 2008 Hangs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

Visual Studio 2008 hangs a lot on my machine.  I work in an team environment using Team Foundation Server and when the server has issues VS hangs forever, sometimes if I have two instances open one of them will hang even if TFS is working.  I try to disconnect from TFS and work offline but even that hangs my VS.  Is there any way to make VS more responsive in case TFS is down?

I have a quad core i5 CPU, 8gb ram, and am running locally (not in a VM).

Comment: I would simply solve the problem that causes TFS to go down so often.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you set VS to [work offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313653/work-offline-in-team-foundation-server/2271119#2271119) and should help with the server timeouts. Also kick the sys admin of your TFS server, it shouldn't be that unreliable.

Comment: seriously.  Adding to what James says, TFS is a server administrator's dream.  It takes very little care and feeding on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is caused simply because the TFS dialogs appear off-screen and it appears to hang.  If pressing Esc "unfreezes" Visual Studio, then this is likely the problem.

I found the solution at: http://www.imiscommunity.com/visual_studio_2008_hangs_tfs_compare_dialog_not_visible

Answer (score -2):

TFS can be a serious nuisance when developing a solution that is used by many team members. Without knowing more specifics about your setup, I would ask a few more questions:

What is your machine spec?

Are all other developer machines the same spec?  Do they experience the same kind of issues?

Have you tried watching the CPU and Memory usage in Windows Task Manager to determine the amount of resources being used?

In summary, I have found that this can often be down to a number of reasons. As a contract developer, I have to use many different systems from the latest desktop with 12GB of RAM and an i7 processor, through to Virtual Machines on a server (my preferred choice because it is scalable and easier to snapshot), down to using older machines that are insufficient for the task (one of the distasteful parts of the jobs is having to request an upgraded machine).

I suggest reinstalling you development environment from scratch, including operating system and everything. Make sure the hardware is the best you can get, and install on a virtual machine instance on that development machine.  That way you can take incremental (albeit slightly large at a fair few GB) backups that will prove handy should you come across an issue.

BTW the most common problem I had was with Visual Studio plug-ins on a system that lacked sufficient RAM.  ReSharper was my biggest offender as it compiles regularly in the background in order to highlight bugs - but personally I would not code without it now.